# Passing an object as a function parameter. Not sure how to access the values.

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I need to write:

```
function remove(str, what)
```

that takes in a string **str** and an object **what** and returns a string with the chars removed in **what**. For example:

```
remove('this is a string',{'t':1, 'i':2}) ====> 'hs s a string'
```

remove from 'this is a string' the first 1 't' and the first 2 i's.

======================================================================

I'm stuck on how to access just the letter or just the number from the **what** object. There isn't a name, just a set of values. Do I have to somehow define it first? Maybe something like this:

```
var a;
var b;
var what = {letter: a, number:b}
```

and then use dot notation to grab each value?

```
 what.letter
```

Comment: Yes. you can access it like that... what.letter or what[letter] assuming letter is a string variable

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` gets you the array of all the keys from the object (i.e. `['a', 't']` in your example). Then you just iterate over that and access the corresponding count.

```
function remove(str, what) {
  Object.keys(what).forEach(function(letter) {
    var count = what[letter];
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path!

Whether or not your function is being called with a the value of an assigned variable or an object literal for an argument...

```
function remove(str, what) {
    ...
}

var what = {
    e: 1
};

remove('hello', what);
// is functionally equivalent to
remove('hello', {
    e: 1
});
```

... your function will still have an object passed in as one of its arguments which you can then access through dot *or* bracket notation.

From there you'll want to iterate over the keys of your object, possibly using `Object.keys` or a `for ... in` loop, to extract the values for performing manipulation on your string.